# building Java classes from two directories using SCons

Tags: java, build, scons

I have a project that has some android specific code and desktop specific code. Since Java does not have something like #ifdef I place the os specific code in its own directory. something like this

```
project
+-- common
|   +-- src
|       +-- com
|           +-- example
|               +-- common1.java
|               +-- common2.java
+-- desktop
|   +-- src
|       +-- com
|           +-- example
|               +-- platform.java
+-- android
|   +-- src
|       +-- com
|           +-- example
|               +-- platform.java
```

Depending on which platform the code is being built for the code from desktop or android is included in the build.

however I am having difficulty building this with SCons

example snippet from SCons build script

```
#target contains the platform we are building on
if target in ['windows', 'linux']:
    java_class_out = env.Java(target='classes', source=['desktop/src', 'common/src'])
    jar_out = env.Jar(target='myOutput.jar', source=java_class_out);
```

when run this will look something like the following:

```
javac -d classes -sourcepath common/src common/src/com/example/common1.java common/src/com/example/common2.java
javac -d classes -sourcepath desktop/src desktop/src/com/example/platform.java
desktop/src/com/example/platform.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
```

The cannot find symbol error is repeated for every symbol that is in platform that came from `common1.java` or `common2.java`

I tried to pass in an array of all of the java files:
Updated snippet from SCons build script.

```
#target contains the platform we are building on
if target in ['windows', 'linux']:
    java_files = ['desktop/src/com/example/platform.java',
                  'common/src/com/example/common1.java',
                  'common/src/com/example/common2.java']
    java_class_out = env.Java(target='classes', source=java_files)
    jar_out = env.Jar(target='myOutput.jar', source=java_class_out);
```

this results in output similar to this:

```
javac -d classes -sourcepath common/src/com/example common/src/com/example/common1.java
javac -d classes -sourcepath common/src/com/example common/src/com/example/common2.java
javac -d classes -sourcepath desktop/src desktop/src/com/example/platform.java
desktop/src/com/example/platform.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
```

What I want SCons to do is output something similar to this:

```
javac -d classes -sourcepath common/src -sourcepath desktop/src common/src/com/example/common1.java common/src/com/example/common2.java desktop/src/com/example/platform.java
```

There was a thread on the Scons-users mailing list asking almost this exact question but no solution was given.

Full email chain that I could find with google:

https://pairlist4.pair.net/pipermail/scons-users/2016-February/004609.html

Anyone know how to get Scons to do what I need? Unfortunately I am stuck with SCons for building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*SCons* is clever enough to add the source folder for your call to the `Java()` method as default parameter to the `-sourcepath` option. But if you simply say

```
env.Java(target='classes', source=['desktop/src', 'common/src'])
```

this will internally result in two separate calls, having the effect of:

```
env.Java(target='classes', source=['desktop/src'])
env.Java(target='classes', source=['common/src'])
```

. That's why you always just get one path, but not the other with your approach.

Instead, you have to use the provided `JAVASOURCEPATH` variable (please search our [User Guide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html), there is only one occurrence) to specify the list of folders that should be searched for *class* or *interface* definitions.

Either

```
env.Append(JAVASOURCEPATH=['desktop/src', 'common/src'])
env.Java(target='classes', source=['desktop/src', 'common/src'])
```

or

```
env.Java('classes', 'desktop/src', JAVASOURCEPATH=['common/src'])
env.Java('classes', 'common/src', JAVASOURCEPATH=['desktop/src'])
```

should do the trick. Note, how I omitted the source/target specifiers in the last code snippet for brevity, but explicitly naming the parameters should work too.

Comment: Thank you.  This helped me so much.  Like most problems its a small thing you just were not aware of.